# Trigger a click on Maps using external link

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, google-maps-api-3

I am working on word-press Site

http://trqdevelopment.co.za/www.dev.abacusspace.co.za/contact-us/

I would kike to achieve this 
http://jsfiddle.net/anganastra/c1L2oea2/

```
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<div id="markers"></div>
```

Is there a simple way on how to do this

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to add javascript then you can use plugin to add multipal marker into google map please check below link of plugins

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-google-maps/

https://wordpress.org/plugins/map-multi-marker/